# GLM Family using tidymodels

Tags: r, glm, tidymodels

I am trying to use the `tidymodels` package for a GLM and want to use the Gamma or Poisson distribution.

Using `glm` I would use something like the following

```
# using glm
mdl <- glm(data = data, y ~ x, family = Gamma(link = "inverse"))
mdl <- glm(data = data, y ~ x, family = poisson(link = "log"))

# using glmnet
library(glmnet)
mdl <- glmnet(data$x, data$y, family = Gamma(link = "inverse"))
mdl <- glmnet(data$x, data$y, family = poisson(link = "log"))
```

How can I achieve the same using `tidymodels`? Note that I am trying to do a regression and not a classification (logistic regression) for which I could use `parsnip::logistic_reg()`.

I found one article on [Generalized Linear Models](https://embed.tidymodels.org/articles/Applications/GLM.html) on tidymodels, which belongs to the `embed` package but does not show how to specify the family.

I would expect something similar to this (which does not work as neither `linear_reg` has the parameters `family` or `link`, nor does `set_engine` support `glm` in linear regression mode)

```
mdl <- linear_reg(mode = "regression", family = "gamma", link = "inverse") %>% set_engine("glm") # or glmnet
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was easier than expected:

```
mdl <- linear_reg(mode = "regression") %>%
  set_engine("glmnet", family = "gamma")

# or 
mdl <- linear_reg(mode = "regression") %>%
  set_engine("glmnet", family = Gamma(link = "inverse"))
```

Comment: When using "glmnet" you should set `lambda = 0` so it does not add a penalty and thus becomes a "normal" GLM without regularization.